# JQUERY UI: Why are my icons and buttons so much bigger than what's shown in the samples?

Tags: jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4

When I try to duplicate the sample found here http://jqueryui.com/button/#icons, I can't seem to make the buttons the same size as what the sample shows.  Even if I paste the text of the sample directly into notepad and save as .html and open in IE, the font is still huge.  I hit F12 and both say that they have a font size of "1.1em" but I don't see any "inherited" size that would be acting as a multiplier.

Shouldn't this just be the correct size using jquery defaults that come with ASP.NET MVC 4?

Comment: Have you checked to make sure you didn't zoom in on the page?

Comment: Is your jQuery-UI theme being loaded?

Comment: @j08691 I was going to ask the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the demo page, the style below is responsible for reducing the size of the text.

```
body {
font-family: "Trebuchet MS", "Helvetica", "Arial",  "Verdana", "sans-serif";
font-size: 62.5%;
}
```

It is in http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/style.css, which is called as a local file (/resources/demos/style.css) both in the demo and the sample code. Since you don't have the file available locally, it isn't used; you'd need to either put the full URL in or download it and place it in the appropriate folder.